# Perl compilation problem that Perl::Critic does not see

Tags: perl

I have this *if* statement that does not pass compilation:

```
        my $string_var;
        if ( $string_var eq "string_value1" || $string_var eq "string_value2" ) &&
           (defined $ENV{VAR_NAME}) {
                die { "error_message" => "error_message" }
        }
```

Neither I nor Perl::Critic see a problem. But Perl says:

```
syntax error at /opt/app_protect/bin/../lib/perl/F5/BdCfg/Bundle.pm line 178, near ") &&"
syntax error at /opt/app_protect/bin/../lib/perl/F5/BdCfg/Bundle.pm line 181, near "}"
```

Can anyone help?

It's CentOS 7.6.1810 with Perl v5.16.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Compound-Statements):

> The following compound statements may be used to control flow:
>  ...
> if (EXPR) BLOCK

What you provide here is not

```
if (EXPR) BLOCK
```

but instead

```
if (EXPR1) && (EXPR2) BLOCK
```

This needs to be enclosed in parentheses in order to be a valid syntax, i.e.

```
if ((EXPR1) && (EXPR2)) BLOCK
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Perl::Critic`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl::Critic)is not intended to handle *syntax* errors; instead it will consider semantic issues, I guess.

Whether `Perl::Critic` could or should handle syntax errors is a different question, however.

When writing Perl code, it might make sense to try validating the code using `perl -c your_program` before trying to run or improve it (as `Perl::Critic` might suggest).
Sometimes `perl -c` gives better diagnostics than trying to run the code.